# run yolov3 in a docker image with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yolo

I am trying to convert YOLOv3 code in a docker image container for a lambda function in AWS.
when I run my app.py code (with Yolo v3 code ) in  the cloud watch I can see that a part of the code runs but it stops at this point

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("./yolov3.weights", "./yolov3.cfg")
```

`yolov3.weights` and `yolov3.cfg` are saved in the var/task/ of lambda function.

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: How does it stop? Does it run out of memory? Is there an error generated?

Comment: No, it ends the request END RequestId

Comment: I tried the same function locally and it works.. I don t know hoe to manage this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I create my docker file and this is the app.py file with yolo

Comment: os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] ='3'
    LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT= os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"]
    

    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT+'/yolo/yolov3.weights ',LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT + '/darknet/cfg/yolov2.cfg')
   
    with open(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT+'/yolo/coco.names','r') as f: